# Ruby on Rails User can only edit a preference, not see list or create new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, updates

I am adding in user preferences in my Ruby on Rails application, and what I am trying to currently do is make it so that a user can only edit their preferences, so not create a new one or view a list of everybody's preferences. This requires a new preference to be made when a new user is made with the id from the users table appearing in the user_id column in the preferences table.

This is the schema:

```
create_table "perferences", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.text     "colour"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "role"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "house_no"
  t.string   "street"
  t.string   "town"
  t.string   "postcode"
  t.string   "email"
  t.date     "date_of_birth"
end
```

Users_controller:

```
 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
     # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
     # accessible to all pages
     session[:user_id] = @user.id
     UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
     redirect_to films_path
  else
     render action: "new"
  end
end
```

And my routes.rb:

```
resources :perferences
resources :prices
# get 'perferences/index', post: 'perferences#new'
# post 'perferences/index', to: 'perferences#new'
# match 'perferences' => 'perferences#create', :via => [:post]

post 'reviews/new/:id', to: 'reviews#new'
get 'reviews/new/:id', to: 'reviews#new'
#resources :showings

get 'sessions/new'
get 'sessions/create'
get 'sessions/destroy'
controller :sessions do
    get  'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    get 'logout' => :destroy
end 

#post 'films/search', to: 'films#search'
get 'films/index'
get 'categories/index'
get 'certificates/index'

root 'films#index'

post 'films/search', to: 'films#search'
post 'films/search_1', to: 'films#search_1'
post 'films/search_2', to: 'films#search_2'
post 'films/search_3', to: 'films#search_3'
post 'films/search_4', to: 'films#search_4'
post 'films/search_5', to: 'films#search_5'
post 'films/search_6', to: 'films#search_6'

post 'films/display_products_by_genre', :to => 'films#display_products_by_genre'
get 'films/display_products_by_genre', :to => 'films#display_products_by_genre'

post 'seats/display_seats_by_screen', :to => 'seats#display_seats_by_screen'
get 'seats/display_seats_by_screen', :to => 'seats#display_seats_by_screen'

post 'screens/display_screens_by_showing', :to => 'screens#display_screens_by_showing'
get 'screens/display_screens_by_showing', :to => 'screens#display_screens_by_showing'

post 'films/multi_find', :to => 'films#multi_find'
get 'films/multi_find', :to => 'films#multi_find'

post 'seats/multi_find', :to => 'seats#multi_find'
get 'seats/multi_find', :to => 'seats#multi_find'
post 'screens/multi_find', :to => 'screens#multi_find'
get 'screens/multi_find', :to => 'screens#multi_find'

resources :users
resources :films
resources :categories
resources :certificates
resources :showings
resources :bookings
resources :seats
resources :screens
resources :reviews
resources :films do
    resources :showings
end
resources :showings do
    resources :seats
end


match '*a', to: 'errors#routing', via: [:get, :post]
```

Note the commented out lines in the routes are what I have tried to get it so that rather than going to the perferences/index page, the user is sent to perferences/edit page where they edit their own perferences.

To clarify what I need to do:

- Make it so that a user cannot go to the perferences/index or perferences/new page but are sent to the perferences/edit page where they edit their existing preferences
- Create a new preference when a new user is created so that they have a preference to edit, even if it has nothing but their user_id so far

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users controller:

```
 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
     # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
     # accessible to all pages
     session[:user_id] = @user.id
     UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
     @user.add_default_preferences # adds default preferences
     redirect_to films_path
  else
     render action: "new"
  end
end
```

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   def add_default_preferences
      Preference.create user_id: self.id # creates 1 preference for user
   end

end
```

Routes:

```
# resources :perferences
# just add route for edit
get 'preferences/:id' => 'preferences#edit', as: :edit_preference # route for editing
patch 'preferences/:id' => 'preferences#update' # route for updating
# just implement your preferences controller
resources :prices
# get 'perferences/index', post: 'perferences#new'
# post 'perferences/index', to: 'perferences#new'
# match 'perferences' => 'perferences#create', :via => [:post]

post 'reviews/new/:id', to: 'reviews#new'
get 'reviews/new/:id', to: 'reviews#new'
#resources :showings
```

Then in your view add

```
   <% if @preference %>
    <%= link_to "My Preferences" , edit_preference_path(@preference) %>
   <% end %>
```

In your `Preference` controller filter that only preference owner can come to edit preference.

Comment: I've just tried this, you've got it working so that a new preference is added when a user is created (thank you), but the routing does not work, it still lets me go to the perferences/index page

Comment: Have you commented `resource :preferences` as I have show you in `Routes` section ?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that bit! Ok, so now a user cannot go to the index page or add a new preference, but how can I do it so that the link on the site's home page (which is views/layouts/application.html.erb) goes to the preference edit page with the user's id? This is the line of code I have tried: `<%= link_to "My Preferences" , edit_perference_path(@perference) %>` but I get the error: `undefined method 'edit_perference_path'`

Comment: I have changed routes, added `as` part for the route to work, and added 2-3 lines of code

Comment: That gives me the following error: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"preferences", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` I think the problem is that the file `<%= link_to "My Preferences" , edit_preference_path(@preference) %>` is added in means that it can be accessed from all the pages, and so no preference is being passed over

Comment: Then you should add `if` statement to show that link for preference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74196/discussion-between-benjs-1-and-nermin).